# How do I find strings that only differ by their diacritics?

Tags: regex, diacritics

I'm comparing three lexical resources. I use entries from one of them to create queries — see first column — and see if the other two lexicons return the right answers. All wrong answers are written to a text file. Here's a sample out of 3000 lines:

```
réincarcérer<IND><FUT><REL><SG><1>  réincarcèrerais réincarcérerais réincarcérerais
réinsérer<IND><FUT><ABS><PL><1> réinsèrerons    réinsérerons    réinsérerons
macérer<IND><FUT><ABS><PL><3>   macèreront  macéreront  macéreront
répéter<IND><FUT><ABS><PL><1>   répèterons  répéterons  répéterons
```

The first column is the query, the second is the reference. The third and fourth columns are the results returned by the lexicons. The values are tab-separated.

I'm trying to identify answers that only differ from the reference by their diacritics. That is, `répèterons    répéterons` should match because the only difference between the two is that the second part has an acute accent on the `e` rather than a grave accent.

I'd like to match the entire line. I'd be grateful for a regex that would also identify answers that differ by their gemination — the following two lines should match because `martellerait` has two `l`s while `martèlerait` only has one.

```
modeler<IND><FUT><ABS><SG><2>   modelleras  modèleras   modèleras
marteler<IND><FUT><REL><SG><3>  martellerait    martèlerait martèlerait
```

The last two values will always be identical. You can focus on values #2 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

The first part can be achieved by doing a lossy conversion to ASCII and then doing a direct string comparison. Note, converting to ASCII effectively removes the diacritics.

To do the second part is not possible (as far as I know) with a regex pattern. You will need to do some research into things like the Levenshtein distance.

EDIT:

This regex will match duplicate consonants. It might be helpful for your gemination problem.

```
([b-df-hj-np-tv-xz])\\1+
```

Which means:

```
([b-df-hj-np-tv-xz])  # Match only consonants
\\1+                  # Match one or times again what was captured in the first capture group
```

Comment: Good call for the conversion to ASCII. I'm not sure the Levenshtein distance is appropriate for this, although I could probably get all pairs with a distance of 1 and go through them manually. Thanks for your input!

Comment: Thanks Paul, I'll give this a try tomorrow afternoon!